# 'npm adduser' returns error 405 IIS 7. WebDAV module

Tags: windows, iis, verdaccio

I setup Verdaccio on IIS 7.5. The web interface is up at the desired address.
When I try to execute `npm adduser --registry http://my.registry.it/`, as requested in the UI, I get an `npm ERR!` saying

**HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed**

It seems a configuration problem with the WebDAV module, but I tried to:

give the WebDAV module various permissions, including executing and scripting and added "all verbs"
manually generate a user entry in ./htpasswd. This step led me to login via UI, but not via CLI
give the user that runs Verdaccio Application Pool all permissions
Please, help me out :)

Screenshots below.

[Web UI](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7755143/63576812-45958c00-c58d-11e9-8362-71bb71e8a403.png)

[The CLI error, put in htm file for convenience](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7755143/63576896-78d81b00-c58d-11e9-8d36-028e88863e35.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a same problem.

I install the `verdaccio` in `iis 7.0` (Windows 7) but it's not working and has error.

when I install the `verdaccio` in iis, I need to install the `iisnode` and `ApplicationRequestRouting`.

also, I need to `URL Rewrite` in iis, that it's not suppotred in `iis 7` (I'm not sure).

I had to install and run `verdaccio` in `iis 8.0` (windows 8) and solved my problem.

after the install in `iis 8.0`, I set this config:

1. open iis and go to your app. (e.g: `http://myregister.com`).
2. go to `handler Mapping`.
3. in right panel, click `Edit Feature Permission`.
4. check the `Read` , `Script` and `Execute`.
5. click the `Ok` button and reset `iis`.

I hope is useful.